# Is there a way to import Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts to WebStorm

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I would like to know if there is a way to import keyboard shortcuts from Visual Studio to WebStorm. I have been using IntelliJ for more than 2 years now and love its interface. So I am trying to shift from Visual Studio to WebStorm.

Answer (score 1):

no, there is no way to do this:( I'd suggest trying the **Visual Studio** predefined keymap (**Settings | Keymap, keymap**). You can re-map actions of certain shortcuts don't match your preferences